# PHP array - Removes other reversed value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4-3
    [1] => 3-4 // to be removed
    [2] => 4-19
    [3] => 19-4 // to be removed
    [4] => 35-10
    [5] => 10-35 // to be removed
    [6] => 11-15
)
```

I want to removes all reversed values and need result something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4-3
    [1] => 4-19
    [2] => 35-10
    [3] => 11-15
)
```

Anyone can help me please? Thanks before :)

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve this yourself. If you get stuck (errors, result not as expected, etc), _then_ it would be appropriate to post a question.

Comment: Can [2] = 10-35? Or only 35-10?

Comment: @neokio : yes, it can. If **35-10** is obtained, then **10-35** should be removed. And also applies to the other

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it, though Eddie's solution is much more interesting ...

```
$x = Array
(
    0 => '4-3',
    1 => '3-4', // to be removed
    2 => '4-19',
    3 => '19-4', // to be removed
    4 => '35-10',
    5 => '10-35', // to be removed
    6 => '11-15',
);

$y = array();
foreach ($x as $k=>$v) {
    $tmp = explode('-',$v);
    sort($tmp);
    $y[$k] = implode('-',$tmp);
}

$y = array_unique($y);
$y = array_values($y);

echo print_r($y);
```

Comment: Yeah, I was greatly helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce` to summarize the array into an associative array. Use `array_values` to convert the associative array into simple array.

```
$arr = //your array

$result = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $v){
    list( $a, $b ) = explode('-', $v);
    if ( !isset( $c[$b . '-' . $a] ) ) $c[$a . '-' . $b] = $v;
    return $c;
}, array());

$result = array_values( $result );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4-3
    [1] => 4-19
    [2] => 35-10
    [3] => 11-15
)
```

Doc: [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Happy to help @Adhy :)

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always as  shown, you could remove each odd index with

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) if($key&1) unset($array[$key]);
```